# How to get username from facebook response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

However the response does not include the current logged in user's username.

I have found references online that use response.username so I assume it was once there, where is it now?

Edit: How does https://ca.madbid.com/login/ do it? I click "Login with facebook" and textboxes appear with my facebook username and e-mail address?

Answer (score 1):

> /me/username is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

You would be able to get the global/real ID of a user with the username, and access to his real URL. Since v2.0 you only get App Scoped IDs and no username to protect the privacy of users.

Answer (score -1):

From the [current Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.2), here is what `/me/` returns.

```
{
  "id": "#######", 
  "bio": "Vidi, Vici, Veni.", 
  "first_name": "Sameer", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "last_name": "Chitley", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/#########/", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "name": "Sameer Chitley", 
  "timezone": -5, 
  "updated_time": "2014-12-29T02:55:12+0000", 
  "verified": true
}
```

You can follow the `response.link` URL, and in the redirected webpage, the username will be formatted as:

```
https://www.facebook.com/username
```

Comment: name is first name, middle and last combined. Not username

Comment: How am I supposed to get the response of facebook.com/username

Comment: you can´t, as i wrote in my answer